# Bash script displaying numbers in a grid as asterisks

Tags: bash, matrix

[image: ASCII bargraph]

I can achieve this with many programming languages but have no clue how to do it in bash, so I'm asking you for help.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Yes, but I got just messy results. I would like to use nested for loops with a matrix variable, but it's not possible I guess, so I don't know how to face the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs adjustments to handle numbers > 9 (they're too long on the last line).

```
#! /bin/bash
main () {
    local numbers=("$@")

    local max=${numbers[0]}
    local i
    for i in $(seq 2 ${#numbers[@]}) ; do
        if (( numbers[i-1] > max )) ; then
            max=${numbers[i-1]}
        fi
    done

    while ((max--)) ; do
        for i in $(seq 1 ${#numbers[@]}) ; do
            if (( numbers[i-1] > max )) ; then
                printf '* '
            else
                printf '  '
            fi
        done
        printf '\n'
    done

    printf '%d ' "${numbers[@]}"
    printf '\n'

}

main "$@"
```

It first finds the maximal number. Then, it lowers the maximum by one down to zero, printing asterisks for numbers that are greater than this "maximum".

Comment: what do local and seq do?

Comment: @Bersekz: See `help local` and `man seq` for explanation.

Comment: this was my idea anyway: http://i.imgur.com/JJGKagQ.jpg but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Bersekz: `echo` includes a newline at the end (unless called with `-n`).

Comment: I know that's OT, but what does $@ mean? Also, is there a way to take this code for getting max and put it into a $max variable instead of printing it? echo "${ar[*]}" | sort -nr | head -n1

Comment: @Bersekz: Read `man bash`. You can't program in a language without learning it.

Comment: @choroba Consider whether fulfilling "gimme code" requests encourages a poster to actually do that.

Comment: I just wanted a fast simple answer: if the output of that sequence of commands can be stored into a variable instead of being printed to screen. I don't have problems going for the normal solution {max=${ar[0]}
for n in "${ar[@]}" ; do
    ((n > max)) && max=$n
done}, but I was just curious to know if it's actually possible. I hope my question doesn't annoy you too much.

Comment: @Bersekz: See "Command Substitution" in `man bash`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, that helped! Also, besides the bash itself, the solution I had thought was clearly overcomplex compared to yours which I find much more easy to read.